# Difficulty solving equation with partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So when I was in school I never went past college algebra.  But I have encountered a specific equation which I want to understand.

At first I thought that an afternoon's focus would be enough to crack it, but no, it was too hard.  I have stuck at it for four days now.  This is the equation:

$\lambda^2\dfrac{\partial^2 V'}{\partial x^2}+t\dfrac{\partial V'}{\partial t}+V' = 0$

The partial derivatives throw me.  Am I understanding correctly that the partial derivative is basically a function that evaluates to a variable value?

Following that presumption, I searched the book I'm reading and found the following:

$\dfrac{\partial^2 V'}{\partial x^2} = V'\dfrac{r_i + r_o}{r_m}$

Thinking I know how to solve that, I did.  I'll call the result $x$

Then I find the following:

$\dfrac{1}{r_i + r_o}\dfrac{\partial^2 V'}{\partial x^2} = \dfrac{V'}{r_m} + c_m\dfrac{\partial V'}{\partial t}$

I think, that looks like what I need, if I isolate it ... So I did this:

$((\dfrac{1}{r_i + r_o}\dfrac{\partial^2 V'}{\partial x^2})/c_m) - \dfrac{V'}{r_m} = \dfrac{\partial V'}{\partial t}$

Then I solved that.  I'll call the result $y$

Finally, I returned to the main problem, which I solved like this:

$\lambda^2x+ty+V' = 0$

Except, it didn't equal zero.  Did I get the concepts correct?

Comment: Are you familiar with a derivative of a function of one variable?

Comment: Not more than I've tried to learn in the last few days, reading about them.  I'm sorry, am I that far off?

Answer (score 1):

This is about an unknown function $(x,t)\mapsto U(x,t)$ (called $V'$ in your question) whose domain $\Omega$  is (part of) the $(x,t)$-plane. Consider a point $(x_0,t_0)\in\Omega$. If you look at this function along the horizontal line $t=t_0$  then you obtain a function
$$\phi(x):=U(x,t_0)$$
of the single variable $x$, which presumably has a derivative at $x_0$. This derivative is called the *partial derivative of $U$ with respect to $x$* at $(x_0,y_0)$, and is denoted by $${\partial U\over\partial x}(x_0,t_0)=U_x(x_0,t_0)\ .$$ 
The partial derivative
$${\partial U\over\partial t}(x_0,t_0)=U_t(x_0,t_0)$$ 
is defined similarly.

The PDE you are given seems to describe some "law of nature" about the unknown function $U$, insofar as the partial derivatives $U_{xx}$ (differentiate twice with respect to $x$) and $U_t$ are related in a particular way:
$$\lambda^2U_{xx}+tU_t+U=0\qquad\forall (x,t)\in\Omega\ .$$
In order to simplify matters I'm going to replace the variable $t$ by a new variable $\tau$ connected to $t$ via $t:=e^\tau$. Since by the chain rule $$U_\tau= U_t\cdot{dt\over d\tau}= U_t e^\tau=t\>U_t\ ,$$ we therewith obtain a constant coefficient equation in the new variables $(x,\tau)$:
$$\lambda^2U_{xx}+U_\tau+U=0\qquad\forall (x,\tau)\in\Omega'\ .\tag{1}$$
The standard recipe for $(1)$ is *separation of variables*: One is looking for a bag full of  solutions of $(1)$ of the special form
$$U(x,\tau)=X(x)\cdot T(\tau)\ .$$
But this is another matter.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I didn't quite catch that.  

The law of nature is the stimulation of a cable by a step current impulse, described in the online book Bioelectromagnetism by Malmivuo and Plonsey (see section 3.6.3).  

In this equation (as I understand it), a spatial constant is multiplied by the change in voltage in respect to x and the temporal constant is multiplied by the voltage in respect to t plus V' which is the difference of the voltage from the resting state.

Do I understand correctly that missing from my information is an equation for V'?  I have V' = Vm - Vr

Comment: @Lurk21: I just had the impression that you don't know what a "partial derivative" is, and wanted to help by interpreting what your PDE is encoding. In fact, "partial derivatives" are about  the easiest things to grasp in the world of multivariate analysis.

Comment: I'm not sure that I do. Here's my take at it. Given an equation that describes a 3-D field, if you define a constant then you can get the slope of two points along the plane of that constant. ?? Am I correct by solving the equation for x and the equation for t, and substituting the results into the main equation? Did I correctly isolate the equation for t? I hope I'm not sounding like an idiot, but in fact I was ignorant of all these concepts until last Friday.